# Android - Using a class in two different projects, but one has package name

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a server/client application. The server is a simple Java server, the Client is an Android application. The client serializes an object called toSend (which does implement Serializable) and then sends it to the Server, which reconstructs it.

However, the problem is, I don't know how to tell server about the toSend object. I moved the toSend class into the Server, but the problem is that my Android uses a package name which the server application does not recognise. I tried different stuff like importing it or not having package names but this broke an array of stuff in different places.

Edit:

Nevermind that, wrong code. Currently my server can't find "toSend" and trying to fix it by "importing" wont work either.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different project `your-project-name-commons`, build it in Maven or Gradle, and then import it in the server and client projects. Have your ToSend class and other classes common to both server and client in the commons project.

Comment: Is there any way to import the server into the already existing project for the App itself? I went with File->Import in Android Studio and chose the Project but it just opened it up in a new window

Comment: No, you shouldn't, and probably won't be able to, import the entire server project into your app. Do you really want your app to be connected to classes which have no meaning for it, like Servlets etc?